# google clound php engine exec not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine

i have a code that use php exec command the code is something like this

```
<?php



    include_once 'retrieve_remote_file_size.php';
    $url=$_GET["name"];
    $q=$_GET["qu"];
       $url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$url;
        $result = array();
        $status;
     $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rClUpezLmrY';


         $string = 'python youtube-dl -g '.$url;
        //echo $string;
        $string2 = 'python youtube-dl --help';
        exec($string, $result, $status);
       // echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'url_orginal'=>$url, 'url' => $result, 'command' => $string));
         $urlf = json_encode(array( ''=> $result));
         $urlf = str_replace('{"":["','',$urlf);
         $urlf = str_replace('"]}','',$urlf);
         $urlf = str_replace('\/','/',$urlf);
         echo $urlf;
        // header("Location: $urlf");

// echo some dynamically generated content here



?>
```

it work fine and gives desired out put in local app engine instance acessed by `localhost:8080`

and it wont work when i deploy it my app is deployed here. http://getvidfar.appspot.com/?name=lztV9TL_nJo it wont work . is it with exec in php could you help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation of the Google appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/?hl=nl#PHP_Disabled_functions) states that this function is permanently disabled.

Comment: then why it work with local engine . running in my system not on app engine after deploying.. or could you suggest me any alternative for this function which i can use

Comment: It seems that all functions for executing cli commands are disabled on the Appengine.

Comment: @user1735121 This is for security reason and because it runs in a sandbox on the production server you should never use it or assume that there will be something installed on their system.

Comment: does anyone know, if these functions are also disabled in google compute engine?